# How to install iOS 5.1 Simulator if I’m not an iOS Developer Program member?

Tags: xcode

iOS 6 is finally out, and so is Xcode 4.5 that comes with the iOS 6 SDK.

Unfortunately, after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, all the previously installed SDK versions have been removed and are to be re-downloaded manually. Same goes for the CLI tools.

But the strange thing happened when I went to Preferences › Downloads › Components and hit “Install” next to iOS 5.1 Simulator. I was prompted for my Apple ID and password at me, so I typed the credentials and confirmed. It turned out I was unauthorized to download it, because I hadn’t enrolled in the iOS Developer Program. (Installing Command Line Tools went just fine, though.)

It was a serious matter to me, because I’m a front-end engineer and test my work in different browsers, including the second-latest major version of Mobile Safari.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Xcode will require your Apple ID in order to access certain downloads, it will usually work even if your are registered with a free account. Usually you only need to be a paid developer to access beta download tools. Do you at least have a free iOS developer account? Or did this particular dowload require you to be a paid iOS developer?

Comment: @Tony: 1) It’s not my own blog post. 2) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.1 Simulator**](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator) for the solution to this problem:

> I headed over to the downloads page for Apple Developers to get the previous version of Xcode (which is 4.4.1). Downloaded the `.dmg` and mounted it. Right-clicked the `Xcode.app` to “Show Package Contents.”
>
> I quickly found what I was looking for in `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` and copied `iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk` to the same location in my `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

The full blog post has some more info.